# Canon 70-200/2.8 IS (mk1) VS 70-200/4 IS

Tags: lens, canon, telephoto

Currently debating which of these lens to get. The f/4 does have the advantage of being lighter, and there have been reviews that it's sharper than the f/2.8 wide open or with both at f/4.

Rather than try to tell me which is better for MY needs, I'd like to hear about your own experience with these lenses, what your requirements are of them, and how you feel they met your requirements.

Any comments about or experience with the 70-200/2.8 IS II is also more than welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How needed is the Image Stabilization on the Canon 70-200 f2.8 L USM lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24673/how-needed-is-the-image-stabilization-on-the-canon-70-200-f2-8-l-usm-lens)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I cannot comment on the f/4 lens, I am absolutely in love with the EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS. Since buying it last year, it became my preferred portrait lens, delivering beautiful bokeh and great sharpness (esp. when my reference is the 28-135mm kit lens). It certainly met my expectations. That said, I knew that it doesn't set a world record in sharpness, so I am prepared for some (very little, don't get me wrong) compromise.

It is considerably more bulky than the f/4 and I recommend you go to the photo store near you to see them both side by side.

Comment: I find the 70-200 to be incredibly sharp, probably canon's sharpest zoom lens (I generally prefer primes).  Its especially sharp backed off from either end slightly, like from 80-190mm

Comment: @Shizam - which of the 5 70-200? As the OP noted, the f/4 is considered as sharper than the f/2.8.

Comment: @ysap Oh, right, I'm referencing the 70-200 f2.8 IS.  Though it should be noted in brick-wall/newspaper testing the 70-200 f2.8 non-IS is sharper than the IS version :)

Comment: @Shizam - I actually assumed that both have the same optics and sharpness. It is not counterintuitive, though, that the non-IS is sharper.

Comment: Thanks all for the input. It seems there aren't many f/4 owners. I'll go to a store to check them both out myself.

Comment: @zweiasakura - Good, and if you feel like you received a satisfying answer to your question, this community encourages the conclusion of a question by "accepting" (clicking on that small "v" under the answer's rating) what you feel as the best answer.

Comment: @ysap you got it